# Variable with special character in a string in zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh, special-characters

I'm trying to create a variable `$creds` using the command line for storing credentials that I use over and over in some terminal sessions. The value in the string looks like `-u myusername -p mypass!word` when it follows the commands I'm using.

The problem comes in with the exclamation point in the password. No matter what I try the login fails when I use `$creds` in place of typing `-u myusername -p mypass\!word`, which works because the ! is escaped.

I've tried `creds="-u myusername -p mypass\!word"`, `creds="-u myusername -p mypass\\!word"` and finally `pass="'pass\!word'"` by itself to see if I can just get the password string stored correctly.

I can't get anything to work when I use the variable as the credentials that follow the command. I have a feeling there's a simple solution I'm missing.

Comment: How exactly do you use `$creds` in a command? It seems you want it to expand to *multiple* words (`-u`, `myusername`, `-p`, `mypass!word`). [This is not a good design](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/108618) in general; but also note [Zsh is different than other shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/108618) and AFAIK unquoted `$creds` will expand to one word. If I were you I would store just the password in the variable. In theory, if the value is properly stored, `"$creds"` (or even `$creds` in Zsh) should work.

Comment: `creds ='-u myusername -p "mypass\!word"'` ?

Comment: @Hannu that didn't work. I decided to throw in the towel and just change the `!` to a different character that isn't reserved in zsh. Then I just set the password to its own variable, works like a charm.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski what I was trying to accomplish is simplify working with the FileMaker Server admin CLI. For example, if I want to list files I'd use the command `fmsadmin LIST FILES -u myusername -p mypassword`. I wanted to just call a single variable after FILES to make things more efficient. Sometimes I end up using half dozen or more commands in a session and it slows me down when I keep entering the same credentials over and over, especially since the real password contains a lot of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `creds` [as an array](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Parameters):

```bash
creds=( -u myusername -p mypass\!word )
```

Then you can pass it to your command simply like this:

```bash
<command> $creds
```